# Thunderbird, debug mode, how to see outgoing imap commands

Tags: debugging, logging, imap, thunderbird

i already enable the debugging mode of thunderbird as stated in

https://wiki.mozilla.org/MailNews:Logging#Other_Protocol_Logging_options_within_MailNews

```
set NSPR_LOG_MODULES=imap:5

set NSPR_LOG_FILE=%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\imap.log

iget an extremly long log file but i can not find outgoing imap commands, for example what is send to the server for login operation? How can i see the outgoing messages? I have currently:

972[df96920]: ec13000:192.168.0.104:NA:CreateNewLineFromSocket: * OK [CAPABILITY IMAP4rev1 UIDPLUS CHILDREN NAMESPACE THREAD=ORDEREDSUBJECT THREAD=REFERENCES SORT QUOTA IDLE] Courier-IMAP ready. Copyright 1998-2005 Double Precision, Inc.  See COPYING for distribution information.

9492[df96e60]: ReadNextLine [stream=dfbc1a8 nb=218 needmore=0]

9492[df96e60]: f81c800:192.168.0.104:NA:CreateNewLineFromSocket: * OK [CAPABILITY IMAP4rev1 UIDPLUS CHILDREN NAMESPACE THREAD=ORDEREDSUBJECT THREAD=REFERENCES SORT QUOTA IDLE] Courier-IMAP ready. Copyright 1998-2005 Double Precision, Inc.  See COPYING for distribution information.

4972[df96920]: try to log in

4972[df96920]: IMAP auth: server caps 0xC2225, pref 0x0, failed 0x1006, avail caps 0x0

4972[df96920]: (GSSAPI = 0x1000000, CRAM = 0x0, NTLM = 0x20000, MSN =  0x0, PLAIN = 0x100000, LOGIN = 0x0, old-style IMAP login = 0x200000)auth external IMAP login = 0x0

..

4972[df96920]: trying auth method 0x4
```

Comment: I can't imagine that Thunderbird will ever log authentication commands because that's a huge security hole. You could use a tool like socat or some other tcp/ssl proxy/toolkit to monitor the data.